# Determine 32-digit Bluetooth ID of Tile tracker

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to write an app to interact with a [Tile tracker](https://www.thetileapp.com/). At this point all I want to do is scan for Bluetooth devices and find it in the returned list. I created an app that does this and it returned the unfriendly 32-digit IDs of all 10 devices found around me, all but 2 of which have included friendly name that I can rule out as not the Tile.

The two remaining IDs are:
**e955aaf6-b4bd-40e2-b452-bd267d287f25

f17664b6-88a3-44a9-955e-e9ef76bee0ff**

Given this link to [Bluetooth Member's assigned uuids](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/16-bit-uuids-for-members) (and filtering to Tile), you can see they are assigned **UUID: 65260, HEX: 0xFEEC** and **UUID: 65261, HEX: 0xFEED**.

Can I use that information to find out if either of the two remaining IDs belong to the Tile?

Comment: No, the uuid provided by core Bluetooth is generated by iOS itself. You need to identify the service identifier for the service that a Tile is advertising. You can the scan for peripherals advertising that service. It should be fairly easy to determine which is the tile by just taking it out of range.

Comment: Does it have some info in the advertisement data?